# Country Code and Phone number from react-phone-input-2

Tags: reactjs, npm, package, phone-number, country-codes

How to store value of country code and only the phone number without country code in two different variables in react js of package react-phone-input-2?
I am using this package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-phone-input-2

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I divided it using a dash `-` between the country code and the actual number. Doing this we can later separate it before submitting. Here's how I did it:

```
<PhoneInput
    value={props.value}
    onChange={(phone: string, country: any) => {
      const reducedPhone = phone.replace(
        country.dialCode,'',);
        props.onChange(country.dialCode + '-' + reducedPhone,);
        }} />
```

So in the end the full number is saved as "countryCode - phoneNumber"
For example: 54-1122334455
And then before submitting we can split it by using:

```
phone_country_cod: form.values.phone.split('-')[0],
phone_number: form.values.phone.split('-')[1],
```